# Como guardar coordenadas X e Y en una variable

Tags: java

no se como guardar coordenadas x e y en una sola variable llamada p1

Este es mi clase coordenada

```
public class Coordenada {
    protected double x ;
    protected double y;
    
    public Coordenada(){
        
    }
    
    public Coordenada (double x, double y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "X= "+x+" Y= "+y;
    }
    
    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }
    
    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }
    
    public void setX(double x){
        this.x=x;
    }
    
    public void setY(double y){
        this.y=y;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase linea en donde tengo como atributos p1 y p2 y esta clase hereda de Coordenada.

```
public class Linea extends Coordenada{
    private double p1;
    private double p2;
    
    public Linea (){
        super();

    }
    
    public Linea (double x, double y,double p1,double p2){
        super(x,y);
        this.p1=p1;
        this.p2=p2;
    }
```

aun me falta completarla pero quiero almacenar en p1 los valores de x e y. es decir que cuando quiera imprimir por pantalla p1 me salga (x,y).

No se como almacenar esas coordenadas en p1. Alguien que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Hola, estas usando mal los conceptos; la relación que existe entre punto y linea es de composición, es decir la clase punto es un atributo de linea.

Comment: Usa la clase [`Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html).